# Date popup on exposed filter

Tags: 8, views, datetime

How can I get a date popup on the exposed filters of a view on D8 ?  I do not see the option, is it on D8 yet?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, exposed filters in Views in Drupal 8 don't use the new HTML5 elements.  Essentially, you get text inputs, selects, or checkboxes/radios.

There is an existing [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2648950) to add this to Drupal 8.

I suspect you could form alter the exposed form to change the types.  This is untested, but essentially what the patch on that issue does:

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['the_exposed_date_element']['#type'] = 'date';
}
```

That won't work for ranges, but it should give you a start.